# Capacitor browser plugin listeners

Tags: java, swift, angular, capacitor

Capacitor browser plugin (latest version, `@capacitor/browser`) works well but it handles only `browserFinished` and `browserPageLoaded` listener.

I actually need to have a listener for messages since I’m using it for external authentication in a Ionic Angular application.

Has anyone implemented others events listener at the plugin level (Android as `CustomTabsCallback` and iOS as `SFSafariViewController`)?

In case it’s not possible, is there a similar Angular plugin that allows for this?

Thank you All

I tried to implement without success event listeners in both files `BrowserPlugin.java` (Android) and `BrowserPlugin.swift` (iOs).